# Single API calling Multiple time in angular

Tags: angular

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  if(changes.formName){
  this.getFormConfigurations(this.formName); 
}

getFormConfigurations(formName): void {
console.log('Inside form call..');
 this.api.getForm(formName).subscribe((result)=>{
 }
}

In API

getForm(name): Observable<any> {
console.log("Inside..API")
return this.http<>....
}
```

I am using this approach to call api on change in Angular , as output in console

```
Inside form call..
Inside..API
Inside form call..
Inside..API
Inside..API
Inside..API
```

As i see multiple API request on this how to avoid this type unnecessary API calls.

Answer (score 0):

`ngOnChanges` will get called every time your `formName` will be changed from the parent component resulting in multiple subscriptions. If you want to call your function only once, you can use attribute `firstChange` of class `SimpleChange`.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
   if(changes.formName && changes.formName.isFirstChange()){
    this.getFormConfigurations(this.formName); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ngOnChanges` lifecycle hook is invoked every time a change in the value of a data-bound property is found. Also, `ngOnChanges` isn't where you should be subscribing to listen to the changes in your observable.

In order to limit the call to the API, you can do the following,

- If the said form is a `template-driven form`

```js
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/common'

@ViewChild('opportunityForm', { static: true }) ngForm: NgForm;

ngOnInit() {
  this.changesInForm = this.ngForm.form.valueChanges.subscribe(x => {
    // Invoke call to injectable
  })
}

ngOnDestroy() {
   this.changesInForm.unsubscribe();
}
```

```html
<form #form="ngForm">
   
</form>
```

- If the said form is a `reactive form`

```js
form: FormGroup;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  
  });

  this.onChanges();
}

onChanges(): void {
  this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
    // Invoke call to injectable
  });
}
```